# Deriving Levi-Civita Connection on the Space of Compatible Complex Structures

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Given a symplectic vector space $(V,\omega)$, consider the space $\mathcal{J}(V,\omega)$ of compatible complex structures on $V$.  We can then regard $\mathcal{J}(V,\omega)$ as a symplectic manifold where each tangent space is given by
$$
T_J\mathcal{J}(V,\omega) \;\; =\;\; \{X \in \text{End}(V) \; | \; JX + XJ = 0, \; \omega(X\cdot, \cdot) + \omega(\cdot, X\cdot) = 0\},
$$

the symplectic form is given by
$$
\Omega_J(X,Y) \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(XJY).
$$

This symplectic form comes equipped with its own natural complex structure where at each tangent space $T_J\mathcal{J}(V,\omega)$ we take the complex structure to be $X \to -JX$.  This then induces the compatible Riemannian metric
$$
\langle X,Y\rangle \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}(XY).
$$

I now would like to derive the Levi-Civita connection for this metric.  I've been given the claim that 
$$
\nabla_tX(t) \;\; =\;\; \partial_t X(t) - \frac{1}{2}J(t)\left [X(t)\dot{J}(t) + \dot{J}(t)X(t)\right ]
$$

where $J(t)$ is a curve in $\mathcal{J}(V,\omega)$ and $X(t) \in T_{J(t)}\mathcal{J}(V,\omega)$ is a smoothly varying vector field along this curve, and $\nabla_t$ is just short-hand for $\nabla_{\dot{J}(t)}$.

My main idea was to start by taking another vector field $Y(t)$ and try to compute
$$
\dot{J}(t)\langle X(t), Y(t)\rangle \;\; =\;\; \left \langle \nabla_tX(t), Y(t)\right \rangle + \langle X(t), \nabla_tY(t)\rangle
$$

and then try to exploit natural properties of the metric.  Alternatively, I've thought about the general formula:
$$
\langle\nabla_XY,Z\rangle \;\; =\;\; \frac{1}{2} \left (X\langle Y,Z\rangle + Y\langle Z,X\rangle - Z\langle X,Y\rangle - \langle Y, [X,Z]\rangle - \langle Z,[Y,X]\rangle + \langle X, [Z,Y]\rangle  \right ).
$$

This problem feels a little confusing to me since the metric itself seems flat.  Would appreciate general suggestions, I'd like the satisfaction of deriving this on my own with some guidelines.

Comment: Since the difference of two connections is a tensor, you know that $\nabla_tX(t) = \partial_tX(t) + T(\dot{J}(t), X(t))$, where $T$ is linear in $\dot{J}(t)$ and $X(t)$. Maybe use that $$\dot{J}(t)\langle X(t),Y(t)\rangle = \langle \nabla_tX(t),Y(t)\rangle+\langle X(t),\nabla_tY(t)\rangle$$ and that $\nabla$ is torsion-free to solve for $T$?

Comment: Why is your $\Omega$ skew-symmetric? Perhaps $\Omega_J(X,Y)=1/2Tr(X^TJY)$?